# What's the right way to globally change the font size?

Tags: fontsize

Inside of a group, a command like `\tiny` has effect only until the group ends. One would like to be able to say `\global\tiny` to have it last after the group ends, but that does not work.

The best that I was able to come up with (described [here](http://texhacks.blogspot.com/2010/03/global-font-size-changes.html)) is the following.

```
\newif\ifhelper
\makeatletter
\def\unithelper#1\@nnil{\global\helpertrue\helper}
\def\helper{\ifhelper\afterassignment\helper\global\fi}
\newcommand*\globalfontsize[1]{%
\begingroup
       #1%
       \def\@defaultunits{\helperfalse\afterassignment\unithelper\global}%
       \let\realvrule\vrule
       \def\vrule{\helperfalse\global\helpertrue\afterassignment\helper\realvrule}%
       \global\helpertrue
       \helper#1%
       \helperfalse
\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

Then you can say `\globalfontsize\tiny` or `\globalfontsize\normalsize` to achieve the desired effect. What is the right way to do that?

Edit: Several people have suggested some variant of `\documentclass[10pt]{article}`. That is not related to my question. I'm using "global" in analogy to the TeX primitive `\global`.

Comment: Without looking into too much detail into the NFSS code, I think this is about the best you're going to be able to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\doglobally}[1]{{\globaldefs=1#1}}
```

Now you can write `\doglobally\tiny`

Comment: Excellent! I had completely forgotten about `\globaldefs`. According to the TeXbook's index, `\globaldefs` appears on exactly 3 pages (not counting the index itself). Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

For at least some font sizes, you can use something like `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`. However, I'm entirely sure which font sizes this works for---I do know it works for 10pt (the default) and 12pt.

Comment: I could have sworn there was a similar answer that I already commented on. My question is not about setting the fontsize for the document. It's about how to change the size in a manner that is analogous to TeX's `\global`.

Comment: @TH. The previous answer has been deleted by its owner.

Comment: But this is what I was looking for when I googled, so I'm upvoting.